# How to make background fit only specified floated child

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I need to make template with column that going from header with title (h1) down, but I can't position it as absolute, because it must get space to move down #next content, that width 100% . . .

On feedle i designed example of what I need, but only problem, that title's background not fit H1 by height. If i move card out from title and make "margin-top: -123px", card will be positioned at bottom of header, but i need position it spaced from header's top.

```css
#page {
  width: 700px;
}

#title {
  background: #acf;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

h1 {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
}

#card {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fafafa;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#content {
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  background: #cad;
  padding: 5px;
}

#next {
  background: #aeb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>TITLE very very very very long TILTE</h1>
      <div id="card">Donec at blandit metus, at ullamcorper urna. Morbi ut ante id tortor tincidunt molestie eu et libero. Sed vel commodo mi. Aenean justo sem, varius et leo a, finibus aliquam magna. Aenean nec erat sit amet enim ultricies dignissim. Proin quis nulla
        in eros elementum facilisis at at ante. Nullam id facilisis mauris, pharetra sodales dui. Fusce lacinia odio accumsan lectus efficitur condimentum. Vestibulum porta ut nulla eget elementum. Integer gravida felis vitae pellentesque gravida. Vestibulum
        molestie, lorem quis suscipit rutrum, ex tortor luctus lectus, eu vulputate sapien nibh vel sem. Nunc vel pretium nulla.

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Donec at blandit metus, at ullamcorper urna. Morbi ut ante id tortor tincidunt molestie eu et libero. Sed vel commodo mi. Aenean justo sem, varius et leo a, finibus aliquam magna. Aenean nec erat sit amet enim ultricies dignissim. Proin quis nulla
      in eros elementum facilisis at at ante. Nullam id facilisis mauris, pharetra sodales dui. Fusce lacinia odio accumsan lectus efficitur condimentum. Vestibulum porta ut nulla eget elementum. Integer gravida felis vitae pellentesque gravida. Vestibulum
      molestie, lorem quis suscipit rutrum, ex tortor luctus lectus, eu vulputate sapien nibh vel sem. Nunc vel pretium nulla.</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="next">any text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also available on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/51uvrzff/

Thanks!

Comment: Image: https://ibb.co/jioWzb
Green card, left tray text and blue header must have dynamic height; 
Green card must have fixed margin from blue header top.

Answer (score 0):

Check example below, if that's what you want:

```css
#page {
  width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#title h1 {background: #acf; border:1px solid black; padding:5px;}

#card {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fafafa;
  float: right;
  padding: 5px;
}

#content {
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  background: #cad;
  padding: 5px;
}

#next {
  background: #aeb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>TITLE very very very very long TILTE</h1>
      <div id="card">Donec at blandit metus, at ullamcorper urna. Morbi ut ante id tortor tincidunt molestie eu et libero. Sed vel commodo mi. Aenean justo sem, varius et leo a, finibus aliquam magna. Aenean nec erat sit amet enim ultricies dignissim. Proin quis nulla
        in eros elementum facilisis at at ante. Nullam id facilisis mauris, pharetra sodales dui. Fusce lacinia odio accumsan lectus efficitur condimentum. Vestibulum porta ut nulla eget elementum. Integer gravida felis vitae pellentesque gravida. Vestibulum
        molestie, lorem quis suscipit rutrum, ex tortor luctus lectus, eu vulputate sapien nibh vel sem. Nunc vel pretium nulla.

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Donec at blandit metus, at ullamcorper urna. Morbi ut ante id tortor tincidunt molestie eu et libero. Sed vel commodo mi. Aenean justo sem, varius et leo a, finibus aliquam magna. Aenean nec erat sit amet enim ultricies dignissim. Proin quis nulla
      in eros elementum facilisis at at ante. Nullam id facilisis mauris, pharetra sodales dui. Fusce lacinia odio accumsan lectus efficitur condimentum. Vestibulum porta ut nulla eget elementum. Integer gravida felis vitae pellentesque gravida. Vestibulum
      molestie, lorem quis suscipit rutrum, ex tortor luctus lectus, eu vulputate sapien nibh vel sem. Nunc vel pretium nulla.</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="next">any text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/51uvrzff/1/

Comment: h1 should be fixed width at left of card, title should be 100% width 
Image: ibb.co/jioWzb

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo element and put below the title like this :

```css
#page {
  width: 700px;
}

#title {
  padding: 5px;
  
}

h1 {
  width: 350px;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
}
h1:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:-100%;
  left:0;
  position:absolute;
  background: #acf;
  border: 1px solid black;
  z-index:-2;
}
#card {
  width: 200px;
  background: #fafafa;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}

#content {
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  background: #cad;
  padding: 5px;
}

#next {
  background: #aeb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>TITLE very very very very long TILTE</h1>
      <div id="card">Donec at blandit metus, at ullamcorper urna. Morbi ut ante id tortor tincidunt molestie eu et libero. Sed vel commodo mi. Aenean justo sem, varius et leo a, finibus aliquam magna. Aenean nec erat sit amet enim ultricies dignissim. Proin quis nulla
        in eros elementum facilisis at at ante. Nullam id facilisis mauris, pharetra sodales dui. Fusce lacinia odio accumsan lectus efficitur condimentum. Vestibulum porta ut nulla eget elementum. Integer gravida felis vitae pellentesque gravida. Vestibulum
        molestie, lorem quis suscipit rutrum, ex tortor luctus lectus, eu vulputate sapien nibh vel sem. Nunc vel pretium nulla.

      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">Donec at blandit metus, at ullamcorper urna. Morbi ut ante id tortor tincidunt molestie eu et libero. Sed vel commodo mi. Aenean justo sem, varius et leo a, finibus aliquam magna. Aenean nec erat sit amet enim ultricies dignissim. Proin quis nulla
      in eros elementum facilisis at at ante. Nullam id facilisis mauris, pharetra sodales dui. Fusce lacinia odio accumsan lectus efficitur condimentum. Vestibulum porta ut nulla eget elementum. Integer gravida felis vitae pellentesque gravida. Vestibulum
      molestie, lorem quis suscipit rutrum, ex tortor luctus lectus, eu vulputate sapien nibh vel sem. Nunc vel pretium nulla.</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="next">any text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make title fixed width and centered by margin: 0 auto, while the h1:before background will be 100% width of the document (#page width 100%)?

Comment: @AlexanderBogatyrev yes sure, it will also work like this ;) you change the value and the before element will stay 100% width... if not we can adjust it of course depending on the new CSS